# Overloading list adding method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, list

I'm writing a basic app based on visual components (button, textbox) and a List of custom class type. My goal is to make textbox auto-update each time I add an element to a list. Is it possible to overload List.Add() method to append also text into a textbox?

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the [BindingList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx#Y4920)

in WPF you can use the [ObservableCollection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms668604.aspx) 
for binding

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution, that I've looked for. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `List<T>` class is designed for performance, not for inheritance, and most of its methods are not virtual, so you can't override them. Instead, you can inherit from `Collection<T>`, which *is* designed for inheritance, and override the `InsertItem` method.

But anyway, I don't think a collection class is the right place to update a `TextBox`... Instead, you should use a collection class that raises events when it's modified (like `BindingList<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`), and react to the events to update the `TextBox`

Comment: Thanks for answer. BindingList with OnAddingNew() method should do the work :)